# DraftMark error - Package not found

Tags: texlive

I compiled my tex file which showed me that the draftmark package is not found. Hence I gave the command, `tlmgr install draftmark` but I get the following error,

```
tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.imsc.res.in/systems/texlive/tlnet
package draftmark not present in package repository.
```

What do I do? I updated my tlmgr with the self option.

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit

Comment: The package is not in TeX Live (see [here](http://texcatalogue.ctan.org/entries/draftmark.html) under "Distributions"). Download it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [CTAN Edition catalogue](http://texcatalogue.ctan.org/entries/draftmark.html), the package ships with MiKTeX, but not with TeX Live. You can download the `.zip` file, extract the `.sty` file (if required) and move it to your personal TDS tree.

By the way, the [`xwatermark`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xwatermark), from the same author, is superior to `draftmark` and ships with TeX Live.

Some other packages offering functionality to add background material:

- [`eso-pic`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic).
- [`draftwatermark`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/draftwatermark).
- [`watermark`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/watermark). By the same author of `xwatermark`; the later supersedes the former.
- [`PGF/TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf).
- [`background`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background).

Comment: Can you suggest a package for this: \usepackage[draft=false,allpages=true,fontfamily=cmr,angle=90,scale=0.2,mark={\fboxsep=35pt\fboxrule=0pt\relax\fbox{-- DRAFT -- }},
color=red!75!green!50,xcoord=-80,ycoord=-20]{draftmark}

Comment: @subhamsoni One question per post, please. Follow-up questions are welcome. That being said, any of the packages I listed above can be used. Since `xwatermark` is from the same author as `draftmark`,  you could read the package documentation to see how to achieve the result with that package. Since I am familiar with the `background` package, you could say `\usepackage[angle=90,scale=1,color=red!75!green!50,opacity=1]{background} 
\backgroundsetup{contents={\fboxsep=35pt\fboxrule=0pt\relax\fbox{-- DRAFT -- }}}` use the `hshift`, `vshift` keys to get the desired placement.

Comment: I wonder why do you use a `\fbox` with `0pt` thickness for the rules.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve and in which position? That would be more helpful than providing some code that might not be compilable.